# Failure to get pagesource/DOM from self-refreshing websocket endpoint

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

That's the website that self-refreshes while adding more text data. In Chrome, viewing page source won't work as it gives a blank result indefinitely, hence I normally use Inspect to view the source.

Using selenium I can't seem to grab the source regardless if I use

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver, chrome_options=options)

html_source = browser.page_source
print html_source
```

or

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver, chrome_options=options)

html_source = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
print html_source
```

The data I want simply comes in as text in the body of the html like so

```
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">: 
: -1
: -1
: -1
</pre>
</body>
```

"-1" denoting the heartbeats from the TradingView server. Note that TradingView doesn't have an official public websockets API hence this is their own internal endpoint I'm trying to utilise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because it not html page but live stream or `text/event-stream`, try using `requests` with `stream=True`

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://.....', stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    print(line.decode("utf-8"))
```

response

```
: 
: -1
: -1
: -1
```